Error while executing topic command : Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1
I have set a 3 Kafka and zookeeper node cluster . I am able to create a single topic in to single server . But when i am trying to use replication factor 3 it is not getting created . Please help .Kafka version (kafka_2.12-3.7.1.tgz )
Command - bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic DGARM-TEST --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 2
I have stared both Zookeeper and Kafka in all 3 nodes and it is up and running
Please help as all 3 node cluster is up and running .
Error while executing topic command : Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1. [2024-07-06 01:07:24,033] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1. (org.apache.kafka.tools.TopicCommand)

How are you testing that all 3 brokers are running and have joined the same cluster?
